# How to publish an automatic post when people connect with Facebook on my website?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm using SDK PHP. I want when people connect with Facebook on my captive portal, "I" can post an automatic status like something like this "You are connected on ... ".
I readed this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-publish_actions
and this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post

and I tried to do this:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{post-id}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

But I don't really understand...
Any help please?

PS: sorry for my english, I'm french.

Comment: You’re not allowed to do any such “automated posts” – users have to trigger every single post actively. And neither are you allowed to specify the message either – it has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by the user. Please go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) before you proceed.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I mean to publish with theirs permissions of course ! So I can't?

Comment: Not “automatically”, not even if they grant your app publishing permission. Again: The user should _actively trigger_ any such posts, your app should not decide to make them on its own.

Comment: Thank you, I will search an other solution.